# Passing RunOptions in TensorFlow C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I currently have a TensorFlow graph that I created in Python and exported (as a protobuf) into C++. I am running enqueue/dequeue ops (`FIFOQueue`) via a `session->Run(...)` call, and need the call to timeout after not being able to run the operation for some time. I am able to do this in Python by feeding `RunOptions` into `sess.run(...)`. Is there a similar way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the headers of the current version (v1.3.0, although it seems to have been the same ever since `RunOptions` was created for v0.8.0) of [`tensorflow::Session`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.3.0/tensorflow/core/public/session.h) and [`tensorflow::ClientSession`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.3.0/tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h), there are function signatures marked as "experimental" that allow you to pass a `RunOptions` object. A pointer `RunMetadata` argument seems also to be required if you call `Run` this way, and looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.3.0/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc) it doesn't seem like you can pass `nullptr`. So you could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int64_t TIMEOUT_MS = ...;  // Timeout in milliseconds
    tensorflow::GraphDef graph = ...;  // Load you graph definition
    tensorflow::Session *newSession;
    auto status = tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions(), &newSession);
    if (!status.ok()) { /* Handle error. */ }
    status = session->Create(graph);
    if (!status.ok()) { /* Handle error. */ }
    tensorflow::RunOptions run_options;
    run_options.set_timeout_in_ms(TIMEOUT_MS);
    tensorflow::RunMetadata run_metadata;
    // Run parameters
    std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor> > inputs = ...;
    std::vector<string> output_tensor_names = ...;
    std::vector<string> target_node_names = ...;
    std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
    // Run
    status = sess.Run(run_options, inputs, output_tensor_names,
                      target_node_names, &outputs, &run_metadata);
    if (!status.ok()) { /* Handle error. */ }
    // Use output
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Looks like the interface has been there for a long time, but since it is marked as experimental it is possible that it displays some bugs or it just changes in an upcoming version.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I ask this is because I need a way to shut down the program once it stops receiving data. Is using a timeout a "graceful" option?

Comment: @nc_ I haven't really used the option myself, but that at least sound reasonable to me, as long as your timeout is long enough to make sure that you don't stop on a delay or in the middle of an evaluation. But you may also research about possible caveats of using that option.